# How to get the Grandtotal value of devexpress pivotgrid?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, devexpress

How can i get a the grandtotal value from a Devexpress pivotgrid using vb.net?

```
Dim dsAccountingCube As New DevExpress.XtraPivotGrid.PivotGridAdomdDataSource
dsAccountingCube.ConnectionString = m_strOLAPConnection

m_pgCircularGauge.DataSource = dsAccountingCube

m_pgCircularGauge.BeginUpdate()
m_pgCircularGauge.RetrieveFields()

For Each f In m_pgCircularGauge.Fields
    Select Case f.Name
        Case "fieldBalance1122"
            f.Caption = "$"
            f.Area = DevExpress.Xpf.PivotGrid.FieldArea.DataArea

        Case Else
            f.Visible = False
        End Select
Next
```

I want to assign the grandtotal value to the needle value of a Circulargauge. As follows

```
Me.CircularGaugeControl1.Scales(0).Needles(0).Value = m_pgCircularGauge.GetCellValue(0, 0)
```

Comment: I suggest you post your question in devexpress support section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the [GetCellValue](http://help.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfPivotGridPivotGridControl_GetCellValuetopic) property found in `PivotGridControl`.

```
m_pgCircularGauge.GetCellValue(0, 0)
```

and it worked for me.